# Solving a set of 3 Nonlinear Equations

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

In the following 3 equations:

$$
k_1\cos^2(\theta)+k_2\sin^2(\theta) = c_1
$$
$$
2(k_2-k_1)\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)=c_2
$$
$$
k_1\sin^2(\theta)+k_2\cos^2(\theta) = c_3
$$

$c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ are given, and $k_1$, $k_2$ and $\theta$ are the unknowns. What is the best way to solve for the unknowns? Specifically, I need to solve many independent instances of this system in an algorithm. Therefore, ideally the solution method should be fast.

Comment: You can add (1) and (3) to give$k_1+k_2=c_1+c_3$$ and then go on...

Comment: Go on with what? That part is obvious, but the rest is the problem.

Comment: I guess you can use @Taro 's answer as a proof of no unique solution since he shows that the system is under determined.

Comment: It is not correct that the system is under determined. See @TMM's answer below.

Comment: Sorry for misleading. But you still need some numerical techniques?

Comment: @AnilBaseski : see Blue's answer below. no need for a numerical computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-write in terms of double-angle expressions, and define values $A$, $B$, $C$:

$$\begin{align}
k_1 \cos^2\theta + k_2 \sin^2\theta = c_1 &\quad\implies\quad \cos 2\theta = \frac{2 c_1-k_1-k_2}{k_1-k_2} & =: A \\[5pt]
2 \left(k_1-k_2\right) \sin\theta \cos\theta = c_2 &\quad\implies\quad \sin 2\theta = \frac{c_2}{k_1-k_2} &=: B \\[5pt]
k_1 \sin^2\theta + k_2 \cos^2\theta = c_3 &\quad\implies\quad \cos 2\theta = \frac{k_1+k_2-2c_3}{k_1-k_2} &=: C
\end{align}$$

Now, $A=C$ implies $k_1 + k_2 = c_1 + c_3$ (but we'd know that simply by adding your first and third equations together), so that $k_2 = c_1+c_3-k_1$ and
$$
A = \frac{c_1-c_3}{2k_1-c_1-c_3} \qquad\qquad
B = \frac{c_2}{2k_1-c_1-c_3}
$$

Observe that you can already write

$$\tan 2\theta = \frac{c_2}{c_1-c_3}$$

which gives you $\theta$. For $k_1$ and $k_2$, note that $A^2+B^2=1$ implies

$$(c_1-c_3)^2 + c_2^2 = \left(2k_1-c_1-c_3\right)^2$$

so that

$$\begin{align}
k_1 &= \frac{1}{2}\left( c_1+c_3 \pm \sqrt{(c_1-c_3)^2+c_2^2} \right) \\
k_2 &= \frac{1}{2}\left( c_1+c_3 \mp \sqrt{(c_1-c_3)^2+c_2^2} \right)
\end{align}$$

(I would guess that the $k_1$ and $k_2$ are simply the two roots of the quadratic ---so that, say, $k_1$'s "$\pm$" is "$+$", while $k_2$'s "$\mp$" is "$-$"--- but this ambiguity is really for you to resolve based on your circumstances.)

Comment: This is a more complete answer. @Blue, you are right about the $\mp$. This is the solution I was looking for. $k_1$ and $k_2$ represent principal surface curvature values, hence in my case it is pre-defined that $k_1 > k_2$. Thanks for the detailed and complete answer.

Comment: There is a sign error at $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Put $u_1 = k_1 + k_2$ and $u_2 = k_2 - k_1$. Then, as Anil Baseski mentioned in the comment, the equation is transformed into
$$ \begin{cases}
u_1 &= c_1 + c_3 \\
u_2 \sin(2\theta) &= c_2.
\end{cases} $$
So it seems that a solution is not uniquely determined from the given conditions.

Comment: You still have either $k_1 \cos^2 \theta + k_2 \sin^2 \theta = c_1$ or $k_1 \sin^2 \theta + k_2 \cos^2 \theta = c_3$ which you are disregarding now.

Comment: I agree with @TMM. But, I couldn't find a way to simplify the whole thing elegantly using elimination of variables.

Comment: @Taro : Please see the other answers. There is a unique solution.

Comment: @meyumer Yes, Blue's answer is a complete one; But please read his answer carefully. Since $\arctan$ appears in the solution, a solution is not uniquely determined.

Comment: it is unique because it is a solution to a problem with 2 roots. and because of the arctan, you get the two different solutions.

Comment: @meyumer As written in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Inverse_functions), $\arctan(x + n\pi)$ gives the same value for $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So you have infinitely many solutions $(k_1, k_2, \theta)$ though it may not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite the system of equations as
$$\begin{align} (k_1 - k_2) \cos^2 \theta &= c_1 - k_2 \\ (k_1 - k_2) \cos^2 \theta &= k_1 - c_3 \\ 2 (k_1 - k_2) \sin \theta \cos \theta &= -c_2. \end{align}$$
Or, equivalently, 
$$\begin{align} (k_1 - k_2) \cos^2 \theta &= c_1 - k_2 \tag{1} \\ (k_1 - k_2) \cos^2 \theta &= k_1 - c_3 \tag{2} \\ (k_1 - k_2) \cos^2 \theta &= -\frac{c_2}{2} \cot \theta. \tag{3} \end{align}$$
Using (1) and (3) we can isolate $k_2$ as $$k_2 = c_1 + \frac{c_2}{2} \cot \theta.$$ Similarly, we can isolate $k_1$ as $$k_1 = c_3 - \frac{c_2}{2} \cot \theta.$$ Substituting this in (3), we get $$(c_3 - c_1 - c_2 \cot \theta) \cos^2 \theta = -\frac{c_2}{2} \cot \theta.$$
From this you can solve $\theta$, and using (1) and (2) you can then also solve for $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Comment: Thanks. Any tips for solving the last equation to find $\theta$?

Comment: Solution to the last equation can be found by the accepted answer given to this follow up question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364883/solution-to-a-trigonometric-equality-equation

Comment: @meyumer I'm sorry, I was in a hurry and did not get around to writing out the last step. But I see you already got the answer you needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$k_1 \cos^2(\theta)+k_2 \sin^2(\theta) = c_1$

$k_1 \sin^2(\theta)+k_2 \cos^2(\theta) = c_3$

$c_1+c_3=k_1+k_2$

$2(k_2-k_1)\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)=c_2 \implies (k_2-k_1)\sin 2\theta=c_2$

$(k_2-k_1) \sin 2 \theta+k_1+k_2=c_1+c_2+c_3$

$k_2(\sin 2 \theta+1)+k_1(1- \sin 2\theta)=c_1+c_2+c_3$

Comment: If the hint results in an obvious solution, I am still not able to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Add and subtract equations $1$ and $3$, giving the system

$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}k_1+k_2&=c_1+c_3\\(k_1-k_2)\sin2\theta&=-c_2\\(k_1-k_2)\cos2\theta&=c_1-c_3\end{align}\end{cases}$$

Then you find $k_1-k_2$ and $2\theta$ by a polar-to-Cartesian transform, giving

$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}k_1+k_2&=c_1+c_3,\\k_1-k_2&=\sqrt{c_2^2+(c_1-c_3)^2},\\2\theta&=\arctan_2(-c_2,c_1-c_3).\end{align}\end{cases}$$