# $(a - b \cot \theta) \cos^2 \theta = -\frac{b}{2} \cot \theta$ ,$\theta=$?

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, numerical-methods

This question is a follow up question to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364565/solving-a-set-of-3-nonlinear-equations/364857?noredirect=1#364857).

In the equation:

$$(a - b \cot \theta) \cos^2 \theta = -\frac{b}{2} \cot \theta.$$

$a$ and $b$ are given. What is the best way to solve for $\theta$? If a direct solution is not possible which numerical method do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 
$$(a - b \cot \theta) \cos^2 \theta = -\frac{b}{2} \cot \theta$$
we get
$$a\cos^2\theta = \frac{b}{2}\cot\theta(2\cos^2\theta-1) =
\frac{b}{2}\cot\theta\cos 2\theta $$
With $\cot\theta = \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$ and $\cos\theta\neq 0$ this gives

$$a\sin\theta\cos\theta = \frac{b}{2}\cos 2\theta$$
which finally results in
$$\frac{a}{2}\sin 2\theta = \frac{b}{2}\cos 2\theta$$
and consequently
$$\tan 2\theta = \frac{b}{a}$$